# How to add br_netfilter to an LXD container

Tags: lxc, lxd

I'm running devstack from within a container I set up using ubuntu 16.04 (both the host and the container).
I see this problem in the container:

```
stack@devstack-2:~/devstack$ ll /proc/sys/net/bridge/
ls: cannot access '/proc/sys/net/bridge/': No such file or directory
```

Whereas on the host it is ok:

```
stack@dl-360-116:~$ ll /proc/sys/net/bridge/
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Aug 24 01:42 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Aug 23 20:47 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 24 01:42 bridge-nf-call-arptables
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 24 01:42 bridge-nf-call-ip6tables
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 24 01:42 bridge-nf-call-iptables
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 24 01:42 bridge-nf-filter-pppoe-tagged
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 24 01:42 bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 24 01:42 bridge-nf-pass-vlan-input-dev
```

Anybody knows how to configure lxd/lxc to add this path in the container?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create or use an existing profile that enables the br_netfilter module

```
$ lxc profile create mod_br_netfilter
$ lxc profile set mod_br_netfilter linux.kernel_modules br_netfilter
$ lxc profile show mod_br_netfilter
  name: mod_br_netfilter  
  config:
    linux.kernel_modules: br_netfilter
  description: ""
  devices: {}
$ lxc launch ubuntu:latest YOURcontainer -p default -p mod_br_netfilter
############ To apply to an existing Instance #####################
$ lxc profile apply YOURcontainer default, mod_br_netfilter
$ lxc restart YOURcontainer
```

Alternatively you can edit any profile you already use to support this kernel module

```
$ lxc profile edit default
```

edit the `config` section to add the configuration key
`linux.kernel_modules: br_netfilter`

Comment: I've got `br_netfilter` in the config, but it still doesn't show. What can be the problem?

Comment: Add profile to existing container: `lxc profile add YOURcontainer mod_br_netfilter`