# LXD: getting /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables

Tags: lxc, lxd

I've enabled br_netfilter in the config of the LXD container, but the path `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` still doesn't appear inside the container.

Similar question:
[How to add br_netfilter to an LXD container](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815993/how-to-add-br-netfilter-to-an-lxd-container)

What's wrong?

(trying to bring up kubernetes inside LXD with `kubeadm init`)

Comment: Posted this issue GitHub here: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/3306